# Can I specify in database.yml that a rails environment should have readonly access to the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have an app with a pretty standard database configuration.  On the live servers, if I want to query the contents of the database I have to run `script/console production` or `script/dbconsole production` and I risk accidentally modifying our data.  I would like to create a new rails environment with readonly access to the same database, so that I can run `script/console readonly` or `script/dbconsole readonly` without the risk.  I've seen solutions that involve adding a new mysql user, or monkey patching ActiveRecord::Base.  I don't want to do that - I want to specify in database.yml that the connection to the database should be readonly.  Is that possible, and if so, how do I do it?  I've tried adding `readonly: true` but it's ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the console in sandbox mode. In sandbox mode, any database changes made while in the console will be reverted when you exit the console.

```
$ script/console --sandbox
```

You can't specify readonly mode in `database.yml`.

Comment: presumably that means a transaction, so I could still inadvertently lock rows in the DB?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried it in my production environment using the command. "bundle exec rails c p --sandbox"

Loading production environment in sandbox (Rails 4.2.7.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit.

But the mongodb changes were not reverted on exiting the console.